# How to use a different email with MailApp in GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, sendmail

I've made a Google Apps Script which is public.  The user makes a query and then they can email the results to themselves.

Using `MailApp`, the email comes from my account.  I have another account which I would like to use to e-mail from.  So I shared the script with this account but I don't have the option to execute as secondaccount@email.com, only firstaccount@email.com since that's the owner account.

Is there a way for me to use `MailApp` with secondaccount@email.com without making it the Owner?

Answer (score 1):

Is not possible without using OAuth and Gmail API. 
Using apps script you have few options like

1) Send email filling the parameter reply To MailApp.sendEmail(to, replyTo, subject, body)

2) Create the script inside your secondary account drive.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deploy your app to be executed as "the user accessing the app" ,it will ask for authorization and then send mails from the user's account.